# In Java, how can I ensure all exceptions that are caught and logged provide a stacktrace in my system?

Tags: java, logging, exception

I'd like to be able to prevent code like this from getting checked in to my code base:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   LOG.error( "DeleteDir of " + tempDir + " failed: " + e );
   throw e;
}
```

This kind of logging only logs Exception.toString() and provides no other details that an operator may need, e.g. a stack trace.

I want to enforce all catch-log blocks to do the following:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   LOG.error( "DeleteDir of " + tempDir + " failed: " + e, e );
   throw e;
}
```

This way I can configure my underlying logging implementation to be as verbose (or as not) as desired.

Are there any static analysis tools, or other strategies that do this?  I looked for a FindBugs check, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you using SLF4J, java.util.Logger, or something else?

Comment: Don't forget to set an uncaughtExceptionHandler to catch the exceptions from threads that die due to uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two open source static analysis tools that are routinely used for checking for undesirable patterns in a codebase: FindBugs and PMD.  I did a quick scan of the standard rule sets for these tools, and I didn't spot any that would check for the pattern you want to eliminate from your code-base.

However, both FindBugs and PMD allow you to write your own custom rules.  It is not that difficult to do.

---

Aside: I hope that examples are "purely for illustration" and that you never deal with exceptions like that in your real code.  If you do, (IMO) then that is a far worse problem than the problem you are currently focusing on:

- Catching and throwing `Exception` is a really bad idea.  When you `catch` the `Exception` class (or `Throwable`), your handler has no idea what exceptions to expect.  If you throw or rethrow `Exception`, the enclosing method must either handle it (see previous sentence) or declare `Exception` in the signature.  That makes it even worse.  If you are not careful, this spreads like a cancer throughout your code base.
- Catching an exception, logging it and then rethrowing it is *generally* a bad idea too.  If you are not careful, the same exception is going to be logged multiple times.  You are better off logging the exception only at the point that it is finally handled.  If you always include the stacktrace, then the programmer has all of the information he/she needs to figure out where the exception was thrown, and the source code will tell him/her all of the precise call chain ... without any need for other logging.

  <sup>However, there are cases where logging all exceptions and rethrowing is necessary.  For example, in applications that comprise multiple components running in different JVMs (maybe on different machines or platforms like AWS Lambda) it can be helpful to implement uniform logging of all exceptions + stacktraces at the platform boundaries.</sup>

Comment: Nope, just for illustration.  The actual code it came from has catch-then-log-and-swallow semantics because it is a Runnable that is scheduled as part of a ScheduledExecutorService and I never want the thread to die.  But I didn't want to paste that code as is because I figured people would say "wtf are you doing!" and detract from the topic :)  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One valid scenario for logging an exception and then throwing it is with AWS Lambda. Throwing the exception will make the invocation fail and log the exception but without context. With Lambda, it's quite useful to log the AWS request ID so you can tell which log line belongs to which invocation.  So if you log the exception explicitly you'll get the context, in particular the request ID, of the invocation where the error occurred. When your Lambda is invoked concurrently, it's helpful to know previous log lines belong to the failed invocation.